# WhatsApp cortando texto após o caractere igual (=)

Tags: api, link, whatsapp

Percebi que o WhatsApp Web, ao encaminhar uma mensagem via link, por exemplo com o link abaixo, ele irá cortar o caracter `=`:

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=551100000000&text=o%20valor%20é%20=%20100
```

O mesmo NÃO ocorre quando o compartilhamento é feito pelo celular, onde utilizo href="whatsapp://send?text=valor = R$ 199,90 - Acesse o link: www.blabla.bla".

Segue o código que utilizo:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".clickWhatsAppChat").click(function() {
    var PhoneNumber = "(11) 0000-00000";
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace("+", "");
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace(".", "");
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace("-", "");
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace("(", "");
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace(")", "");
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      var confirma = confirm("Se você tiver o WhatsApp instalado, iniciará uma conversa com " + PhoneNumber + ".");
      if (confirma == true) {
        window.location.href = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" + PhoneNumber + "&text=valor=R$199,90";
      }
    } else {
      var confirma = confirm("Faça o login no WhatsApp Web e AGUARDE ALGUNS SEGUNDOS até que a coversa com " + PhoneNumber + " se inicie.");
      if (confirma == true) {
        window.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" + PhoneNumber + "&text=valor=R$199,90", "_blank");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Alguém já passou pela mesma dificuldade? Se sim, como resolver?

Comment: Xará, talvez você precise encodar a string pra não conflitar com os caracteres reservados. Você pode usar [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) pra isso

Comment: O que quer dizer com "_cortar_"?

Comment: sim, posso fazer isso, mas a questão é que no link para celular, que direciona para o aplicativo, não tem esse conflito...

Comment: A VERDADEIRA RAZAO DISSO SAO CARACTERES ESPECIAIS. espaços e algums caracteres não sao enviados. ACREDITE. PASSEI POR ISSO E RESOLVI TIRANDO OS ESPAÇOS.